# angular ui-model popup is not working with bootstrap 3

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

```
<div ui-modal class="fade" ng-model="campaignSettings" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
        <div class="modal-header">  
            <a class="close" ng-click="campaignSettings=false">x</a>  
            <h3>Link Settings</h3>  
        </div>          
        <div class="modal-body">    
            text
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">  
            <a class="btn btn-default" ng-click="campaignSettings=false">Close</a>  
        </div>          
    </div>
```

by using angular + bootstrap2

now this ui-model is not working with bootstrap3

any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

There's a branch with templates for Bootstrap 3:
https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/bootstrap3

You can use those; [see a basic demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/bwP9lsyNlsyJls9AuXvB?p=preview).